# Observables Mess - Get Data Until There is No More to Get

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am using Typescript and Angular.
I have an Observable created with a while loop that checks if there is more rows. I set it to false within my getRows().subscribe() when the newRows.length is 0. This however does not effect the while loop, and subscriber.next() is ran infinitely.

My "this.employeesService.getRows" simply returns an array of 100 items per request, until the last one of course.

```html
thereIsMoreRows: boolean = false;
  firstIndex = 0;
  lastIndex = 100;

  employees$: Observable<any> = new Observable(subscriber => {

    console.log("employees observable");
    console.log("-1 this.thereIsMoreRows", this.thereIsMoreRows);
    subscriber.next();

    while(this.thereIsMoreRows) {
      console.log("0 this.thereIsMoreRows", this.thereIsMoreRows);
      subscriber.next();
    }
  });

  // /** Gets the list of employees from the server */
  getEmployees() {
    
    this.employees$.subscribe( next => {
        console.log("next", next);

        console.log(`next firstIndex: ${this.firstIndex}, next lastIndex: ${this.lastIndex}`);

        this.employeesService.getRows(this.firstIndex, this.lastIndex).subscribe(
          newRows =>
          {
            console.log("newRows.length", newRows.length);
            console.log("1 this.thereIsMoreRows", this.thereIsMoreRows);
            if (newRows.length > 0) {
              console.log("1.5 this.thereIsMoreRows", this.thereIsMoreRows);
              this.gridApi.applyTransaction({
                add: newRows,
                addIndex: this.firstIndex
              });
            }
            else {
              this.thereIsMoreRows = false;
            }
          });
        
        //increment indices
        this.firstIndex = this.lastIndex; //start from last since it is ommitted during server slice
        this.lastIndex = this.lastIndex + 101; //to grab x we need to add x + 1 to lastIndex
    });
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this Observable mess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [expand](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/expand) from rxjs? It handles recursive observable calls until a condition is met.

For example, something like this:

```
import { EMPTY } from "rxjs";
const getRows$ = this.employeesService.getRows(this.firstIndex, this.lastIndex);
getRows$.pipe(expand(rows => 
                     rows.length === 0 ? 
                     EMPTY   // to stop the recursivity
                     : getRows$
  ).subscribe(
  newRows =>
  {
   if (newRows.length > 0) {
    this.gridApi.applyTransaction({add: newRows,addIndex: this.firstIndex});
    this.firstIndex = this.lastIndex; 
    this.lastIndex = this.lastIndex + 101; 
    return this.employeesService.getRows(this.firstIndex, this.lastIndex);
  } else {
    return EMPTY;
}
}));
```

Comment: To get this to compile I had to do pipe and expand inside the pipe. I couldn't get Rx.Observable.empty() to work so I instead used import { EMPTY } from "rxjs"; for some reason the recursivity does not stop though, and I end up with duplicates in my ag-grid.

Comment: Good remarks, I didn't test the code, I've edited my answer, I added the "else" inside the subscribe, maybe it's because of that you had an unstoppable loop.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like so:

```js
  getEmployees() {
    this.employeesService.getRows(this.firstIndex, this.lastIndex).subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result.results) {
          this.gridApi.applyTransaction({
            add: result.results,
            addIndex: this.firstIndex
          });
          this.firstIndex = this.lastIndex; //start from last since it is ommitted during server slice
          this.lastIndex = this.lastIndex + 100; //to grab x we need to add x to lastIndex
          this.getEmployees(); //recursive till we hit the point when newRows.length == 0
        }
        else {
          return;
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: To prevent any memory leak, you should store each of your subscription in an array and unsubscribe from all at the end of your method

Comment: Thanks! I will do that.